# Make: How could i change the path of a files which matches certain pattern

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I am new to GNUmake.

I have a requirement to replace the file paths based on certain condition.

```
TARGET_EXCEPTION := /home/ip/lib_build
TGT_TOOLS := /demo/build/new_project
ifdef SET_BUILD
 ifneq (0,$(RELEASE))
   FILES += $(addprefix $(TARGET_EXCEPTION)/tools/test/,$(subst $(TGTTOOLS)/tools/test/,,$(RELEASE_FILES)))
 endif
endif
```

RELEASE_FILES variable has multiple file paths assigned. Out of those files i am interested only in folders with $(TGT_TOOLS)/tools/test/ and replace it with $(TARGET_EXCEPTION)/tools/test/.. Is there anything wrong in my above code? Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a requirement to replace the file paths based on certain condition.

I daresay the actual requirement is probably more like "the tests should be installed in the directory named by `$(TARGET_EXCEPTION)` in a release build, but in the directory named by `$(TGT_TOOLS)` otherwise.  The distinction is important, because it is clearer and more portable to just assign the path appropriately in the first place.

That might look something like this:

```
# Possible test install locations
TARGET_EXCEPTION := /home/ip/lib_build
TGT_TOOLS := /demo/build/new_project

####
#
# Determine which location to use
#

ifdef SET_BUILD
  TEST_INSTALL_RELEASE := $(RELEASE)
else
  TEST_INSTALL_RELEASE := 0
endif

ifneq (0,$(TEST_INSTALL_RELEASE))
  TEST_DIR := $(TARGET_EXCEPTION)
else
  TEST_DIR := $(TGT_TOOLS)
endif

#
####

# Define the release files in the desired location from the start
RELEASE_FILES := \
  # ...
  $(TEST_DIR)/tools/test/test1 \
  $(TEST_DIR)/tools/test/test2 \
  # ...

# No substitution needed; the targets are already named correctly
FILES += $(RELEASE_FILES)
```

> Is there anything wrong in my above code?

It attempts to implement a poor approach.  Also, it very well might not interoperate as you require with your makefile's rules related to the affected files.  The above might also have the latter problem, but in that case there is also a clear solution: refer to the affected files everywhere by the name format given in the example.